# JSON schema validation not working in rest assured with body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("get.json"));

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

JSON schema validation not working in rest assured with body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("get.json"))

i am using https://jsonschema.net/ for generating JSON schema for my JSON schema generation.Even though i have changed the converted schema so that the test should fail but giving this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: The content to match the given JSON schema.
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [$id]
level: "warning"
schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/D:/workspace/restAssuredFramework/target/test-classes/get.json#","pointer":""}
domain: "syntax"
ignored: ["$id"]
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [$id]
level: "warning"
schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/D:/workspace/restAssuredFramework/target/test-classes/get.json#","pointer":"/properties/IntegrationEntities"}
domain: "syntax"
ignored: ["$id"]
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [$id]
level: "warning"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide a bit more infos like the test code. Otherwise it would be hard to help you.

Comment: the test code is below
given().headers(getHeadersFromPropertiesFile()).when().get(API_URL).then().assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("get.json")); 
where get.json is exactly same as the response which we want to compare but when we change the get.json file ,  basically it should fail but it doesn't .